# Unity: How to detect mouse click in a script without attaching the script to an object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity, using C#, how do I detect a click anywhere in the screen, without attaching the script to an object?

To be specific, I am looking for individual clicks, not mouse downs.

e.g.  the code below checks for mouse down, but I want clicks instead

```c#
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    // 1
    Vector3 currentPosition = transform.position;
    // 2
    if( Input.GetButton("Fire1") ) {
                // Do something
            }
     }
```

Comment: You have to attach a MonoBehaviour class to an object to get input. What is your definition of a "click" -- `GetMouseUp` within a timeframe from the last `GetMouseDown`? http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonUp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need a MonoBehaviour so that you can use the `Update()` function to your advantage. Just attach it to an empty GameObject, it is not uncommon for a game to have one empty GameObject that has a few scripts that handle certain things.

Check for `GetMouseUp` to count your clicks.